# How to set Navbar height in Xcode storyboard?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, ios5, xcode-storyboard

I'm developing a menu system for an iPhone game using the new storyboard feature in Xcode. I have a navigation controller as the initial view controller, and it works great when everything is in portrait orientation. But if I want my menus in landscape orientation, the nav bars that propagate across the child views are the wrong size!

In portrait mode the nav bar defaults to 44 points high, but in landscape mode it changes to 32 points to make more space on the screen. But in the storyboard there doesn't seem to be a way to change the height and it seems stuck on 44. The height option in the size editor is grayed out for the navigation bar.

Is there any way to set the height of the navbar in the storyboard so that everything matches what will actually happen?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?  This is biting me in the butt right now.

Comment: @jsd, unfortunately no. I'm just living with it at this point. I ended up setting the navbar to be partially transparent so I can just plan for the whole view instead of trying to line something up so it fits just underneath the navbar. I just know a little less will be covered up than what shows in the storyboard.